# How do I edit files in Stata?

Tags: stata

I'm using Stata 11 on OSX, new to Stata. Someone has sent me a `.do` file and I want to amend it and run it.

If I open the file in Stata (using File > Open), I see the file appear like this:

[image]

I can click on text, but I don't seem to be able to edit or select it. It's almost like an image rather than a text file.

So, um, how do I edit the text?

All of my Googling suggests I need to use the "do-file editor" - I'm not sure if this is it, and if so, how I set it to edit mode!

Comment: I don't use OS X but a generic tip is that you should go straight to StataCorp's documentation. See http://www.stata.com/manuals14/gsm.pdf  for one, or http://www.stata.com/bookstore/getting-started-mac/

Answer (score 1):

Open a new .do file `(ctrl+9)`. Then in that go file>open and open the .do file in the editor. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I think what was confusing me is that the mouse does not work in the Stata editor at all! I guess this is by design - only the keyboard does anything.